# Python, finding <a> class, saving text within to a variable, using the variable to search for an image by title, opening the image link

Tags: python

I am new to python and have been practicing web parsing. The webpage information that I am trying to parse contains info like this:

```
<a class="nickname" href="/users/2236955">random_text_that_changes_</a>
<img alt="Brooklyn_: Toy store haul..." title="Brooklyn_: Toy store haul..." width="110" src="https://pic1.com/2236/2236955/000538a9-4905-04ce-a037-6eddb2c54021_110.jpg?token=1573257600_040bf05e8d8a9cc84211d7294292f9cd999853f3c56d82b790b47a0532d96795">
```

I need to be able to find the a class "nickname", save the text that is including within to a variable, as an example, for this profile it would be 'random_text_that_changes_'. Once the text is saved to the variable, search the page for an image title with partial text matching "random_text_that_changes_" and then click the link. I am really having trouble with accomplishing all the steps.

Code I have so far:

```
browser.get(page_link)
time.sleep(2)
variable = browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('title')
browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text(variable).click
```

Comment: Have you heard of BeautifulSoup? If not see here: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigating-the-tree

Another one to take a look is (MechanicalSoup)[https://mechanicalsoup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html]

Comment: I am currently using selenium to open the browser, correct me if I am wrong, but doesn't beautifulsoup need the web page to be downloaded and saved before parsing? The web page is fairly large and doing this on multiple loops will use more data than I would like to.

Comment: Since the question didn't have the full context, I suggested the frameworks which helps with parsing web pages. If you want to open a website and parse its content, then MechanicalSoup might be a better option for you. Check the tutorial link I mentioned aboved.

Comment: when you use selenium then web page you have already downloaded to web browser which uses it to display page. You can get it using `browser.page_source` and you can use it with `BeautifulSoup`. But `Selenium` has many different methods `find_element_by_...` - ie,`find_element_by_class_name`, `find_element_by_css_selector`, `find_element_by_xpath` so you can use them to get `find_element_by_class_name("nickname")`. BTW: `Selenium` has also functions `find_elements_by_...` with `s` at the end of word `elements` to get many elements, not only first one.